# Jquery script does nothing on one page but on another

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web, html

I have a little JQuery script that I got from a guy with a foreign page.

```
$(function () {
    var $txt = $('input[id$=TextBoxFiltroProv]');
    var $ddl = $('select[id$=DropDownListProv]');
    var $items = $('select[id$=DropDownListProv] option');

    $txt.keyup(function () {
        searchDdl($txt.val());
    });

    function searchDdl(item) {
        $ddl.empty();
        var exp = new RegExp(item, "i");
        var arr = $.grep($items,
                function (n) {
                    return exp.test($(n).text());
                });

        if (arr.length > 0) {
            countItemsFound(arr.length);
            $.each(arr, function () {
                $ddl.append(this);
                $ddl.get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
            }
                );
        }
        else {
            countItemsFound(arr.length);
            $ddl.append("<option>No Items Found</option>");
        }
    }

    function countItemsFound(num) {
        $("#para").empty();
        if ($txt.val().length) {
            $("#para").html(num + " items found");
        }
    }
});
```

It works on a page that has already rendered everything (HTML controls) and has some of the elements inside an update panel. But on the other page I have 2 update panels, and one Panel (It starts hidden). The controls are inside the ASP.net PANEL. ¿Is the problem that the controls are hidden? And in that case ¿How do I tell JQuery to start this piece of code when the panel is visible and its controls have been rendered? I think I missed something but I cant see it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, hidden elements (e.g. `display:none;`) are not returned via selectors (e.g. `document.getElementById`).

Comment: a hidden ASP panel, will have no html in it to select. If you place the code in the following function, it will run when the page gets reloaded with the new update panel in it: jQuery(document).ready(function () { .... });

Comment: have you got some basic html to show this?

Comment: Its basicaly <asp:UpdatePanel><asp:ContentTemplate><asp:Panel>CONTROLS HERE</Panel></Content></udp>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sovled this problem, it was because of the updatepanels, I added the following code, surrounded my main code with a function called BindEvents and in update panel I added this script:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel...>
<ContentTemplate>
     <script type="text/javascript">
                    Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
     </script>
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are being added dynamically in an update panel then you will have to set up delegates to bind to the events. That way, when the elements are added dynamically, jquery will be sure to bind the events as declared.

Below is an example where on the `document` I want to bind any element with the given selector `input[id$=TextBoxFiltroProv]` to the `keyup` `event` that is existing `onload` or is added to the DOM after the `document` is `ready`.

Example:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[id$=TextBoxFiltroProv]', function () {
      searchDdl($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer that works on some scenarios as well.